# Android intent extra does not restore on resume

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I have 2 activities, one sends data to the other by intent.

I have 2 editText for users to input the value
after saved, it will show in the editText box

```
savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
first = savePreferences.getString("first", "1st");
second = savePreferences.getString("second", "2nd");

editf1.setText(first);
editf2.setText(second);
```

In Activity1

```
public static String filename = "myfile";
SharedPreferences savePreferences;
savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor saveEditor = savePreferences.edit();            
saveEditor.putString("first", edit1.getText().toString());
saveEditor.putString("second", edit2.getText().toString());              
saveEditor.commit();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

//put the retrieved data in extras      
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("firststr", first);
extras.putString("secondstr", second);
myIntent.putExtras(extras);

startActivity(myIntent);
```

In Activity2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();         

if (extras != null) {
     firstval = extras.getString("firststr");
     secondval = extras.getString("secondstr");
}
```

I have 2 TextView to show the data passed from Activity 1

```
if (firstval == null || firstval == "")
     textView1.setText("empty");
else
     textView1.setText(firstval);

if (secondval == null || secondval == "")
     textView2.setText("empty");
else
     textView2.setText(secondval);
```

When I clicked the save button the value is saved into shared preference and the intent will start and go to Activity2.
At this stage, the value saved and passed from Activity1 are able to be shown in my TextViews.

But once I refresh the page, the TextView show empty instead.

When my application starts, Activity2 will start first and TextView show empty too.
How do I make it such that when I open my app or refresh my app, the value of the intent extra is always there? instead of going to Activity1 to save it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the values to be saved in the Intent. The way you are using SharedPreferences is deprecated.

prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

To save and retrieve at appropriate places String values in prefs, you can use the following:

```
// Retrieve the saved values in Activity2
    private String getCurrentDefaultHomeApp(){
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());.getString("Key", "DefaultValue");
    }

// Put this in Activity1
    private void setCurrentDefaultHomeApp(String appId){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());.edit();
            editor.putString("Key", "value");
            editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: the code for SharedPreferences actually works, however everytime i have to go from activity1 to save the value and it will show in activity2. However when I start my app with activity2 it does not show.

Comment: It works because you are fetching it from Intent you send. You need to use an application wide SharedPreferences as I mentioned and access it in your Activity2 using the getXXX method similar to the one I wrote.

Comment: There is nothing deprecated about that usage of SharedPreferences. That said, SPs, initial intent extras, and saved instance state bundles are not the same. It sounds like the OP wants to use saved instance states but is using SPs instead when storing.